# When using multiple clones of a machine, what steps are nessecary to make them unique?

Tags: virtual-machine, cloning

I have a base image of Ubuntu 20.04 in vSphere with some of the nessecary configurations for my environment. When I need a new Linux server, I'd like to be able to use a clone of this image as a starting point. The number of Linux devices in my environment will be limited enough that it's not likely to be worth investing (effort) in setting up a more robust configuration and deployment setup than this.

My concern is that if I use this method, certain values that should be unique will be identical.

I have in mind:

- The hostname and the `/etc/hosts` file
- The `/etc/machine-id` file
- The MAC address (this appears to be different across clones on its own).
- Static IP (in my case, there is none)

Beyond this, what should I have in mind, and how important is it that these be made unique?

Comment: Add ssh host keys (`/etc/ssh/ssh_host*`) to the list.

Comment: and add various UUID, like GPT partitions and especially LVM-related UUIDs (else a system trying to use a clone disk's LVM, for example for a rescue operation, will be confused by the identical uuids. Even then the identical name won't help command syntax). Of course configuration must match (eg: /etc/fstab or content of /etc/lvm)

Comment: You might find [cloud-init](https://cloud-init.io/) useful (install the `cloud-init` package).

Comment: The MAC address is normally gotten from local network devices - unless spoofed by software. Read man machine-id...

Comment: Take a look at the [virt-sysprep](https://libguestfs.org/virt-sysprep.1.html) command. which is designed exactly for the purpose of unique-ifying cloned virtual disk images. There are a number of operations discussed in the man page that cover things that haven't come up in your question or in the comments.

Comment: If you use Ubuntu's OEM feature, the final configuration will make the systems unique. See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview)